# Durable Function exception: “Unable to find an Azure Storage connection string to use for this binding

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm getting next error:

Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask: Unable to find an Azure Storage connection string to use for this binding.

Question:

It appears to be the durable function that's complaining about the missing connection string. However, I do not have the option for setting Azure Storage on first place ,where I can bind azure storage
[image]

Repro steps:

```
Open any browser and use only UI (without any CMD commands)
Create Function App with next parameters:
Runtime stack: .NET 3.1
Hosting Plan: App service plan
Operating System: Windows
Region: North Europe
Shared infrastructure: 1 GB memory
Monitoring: Application Insights - Not enabled

Add DurableFunctionsHttpStart
Navigate to "Overview" tab and you'll see that error
or
hit "Code + Test" button for DurableFunctionsHttpStart
```

Comment: no there is no such error for me, have you created a new storage account when creating the function?

Comment: @Sajeetharan I can't find that option to link storage account, while create function  steps..please find screenshots

Comment: @JJohn - the storage account option comes before "Operating system" option which I don't see in the attached screenshot which is strange :). Is it due to you have don't have quota left for storage accounts or the location chosen on Basic section does not allow storage account creation?

Comment: @Sajeetharan ..Selected location is central us

Comment: you mean the storage account?

Comment: @Sajeetharan function app

Comment: you should see a storage account option? do you see that or not?

Comment: @Sajeetharan I can 't see that option from hosting  tab

Comment: @JJohn - log a support ticket on Azure. They can assist by providing the information that why the storage account options is not visible while creating a new function app.